# Multiplying certain list elements by certain numbers

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the list:

```
List1={{7, -0.9}, {10,-1}, {12, -2}, {15, -2}}
```

Would like to receive the next list:

```
List2={{7, -0.9*2*List1[[1]][[1]]}, {10,-1*2*List1[[2]][[1]]}, {12, -2*2*List1[[3]][[1]]}, {15, -2*2*List1[[4]][[1]]}}
```

Those multiply all second elements of the list by 2, and then by the corresponding first element
How can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
List1 /. {f_, l_} :> {f, 2*l*f}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
MapApply[{#1, 2 #1 #2}&]@List1

(* {{7, -12.6}, {10, -20}, {12, -48}, {15, -60}} *)
```

Or

```
{#[[All,1]], 2 #[[All,1]] #[[All,2]]}&@List1//Transpose
```